# Can I default to T-SQL only view in VS 2012?

Tags: development, visual-studio-2012

When creating new tables in a database project in VS 2012, opened sql files default to a split view. One is the **T-SQL** text editor view, and the other is the **Design** view. I've never used the design view, and probably never will. I just prefer the text editor. Is there a way to tell VS to default to the T-SQL view?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found an option to turn off the design portion of the split view. Nor have I found a way to have the order of the windows remembered after closing a window, which is annoying!

However, if you want to ditch the SSDT editor completely you can change the default for .sql files in Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension, as shown below:

[image: VS/Tools/Options]

Answer (score 2):

[image: VS2012 T-SQL text editor default view]

Alternatively you can choose the editing experience 'Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor' for 'sql' extention files. This option will keep the T-SQL specific key word highlighting features intact when opening the file.